# Comparing or checking tables and other objects in a database against a schema or script

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-schema

I'm doing a sort-of self check installing page in asp.net site where the existing database needs to be updated against latest schema. What's the best way to do it? Previously we used one of RedGate Wins Software to compare the database and generate a update script to be executed on the existing client databases.

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate offers an API so it can be run without the GUI. Not sure how this affects licensing though.

Otherwise, some ideas:

- test for missing objects and CREATE
- run ALTERs on code where possible
- run a script if the version (in a udf or table) is lower

if you have a script that does a complete transactional upgrade generated, by say Red Gate, you can use this: all you need is a test to decide whether to run it or not.

One point: to make DDL change requires db_owner or ddl_admin rights: does yoru app run with these rights day to day?

Comment: thanks gbn. didn't realize that red gate has the api. for the time being, it's okay not to update the database objects, but to check if the database is still up to date, otherwise we will run the scripts with one of db-owner account manually.

Comment: It's not clear but this is an example. Effectively you run command line compares <http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=SQL%20Compare&c=SQL_Compare\help\8.50\sc_cl_integratingwithapplications.htm>